# Cant wrap <Tooltip> component around <DatePicker> component - Not forwarding props correctly error

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Link to code: https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-bogdan-2pt7tn?file=/demo.tsx

When I wrap a MUI `Tooltip` control around a `DatePicker` I get the following `console` error:

> MUI: The `children` component of the Tooltip is not forwarding its
> props correctly. Please make sure that props are spread on the same
> element that the ref is applied to. 
> in Tooltip (created by BasicDatePicker) 
> in BasicDatePicker

Here's the code...

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Dayjs } from "dayjs";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import { AdapterDayjs } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs";
import { LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider";
import { DatePicker } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker";
import { Tooltip } from "@mui/material";

export default function BasicDatePicker() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState<Dayjs | null>(null);

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
      <Tooltip
        title={"Choose Date"}
        placement="bottom"
        data-cy={"business-identity-date-of-formation-tooltip"}
      >
        <DatePicker
          label="Basic example"
          value={value}
          onChange={(newValue) => {
            setValue(newValue);
          }}
          renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
        />
      </Tooltip>
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```

If I replace the `DatePicker` with something like an `IconButton` it works fine.

On my real dev project this is within a `Formik` form too. The error is a bit different:

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop 'children' supplid to 'ForwardRef(Tooltip)'. Expected an element that can hold a ref. Did you accidently use a plain function component for an element instead?

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57527896/material-ui-tooltip-doesnt-display-on-custom-component-despite-spreading-props/57528471#57528471) a MUI component should be supported by the `Tooltip`....

> Your Tooltip is not working properly because the child of a Material-UI Tooltip must be able to hold a ref.
> The following can hold a ref:
> **Any Material-UI component**

I also saw [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58616407/wrap-datepicker-in-a-material-ui-tooltip-fails-with-forwardreftooltip-error). But I wanted the `Tooltip` at the `DatePicker` level, not at the textbox level.

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57527896/material-ui-tooltip-doesnt-display-on-custom-component-despite-spreading-props

Comment: Thanks. That's the one I referenced that said any mui comp can hold a ref.

Comment: Well, try implementing it as a forwardRef as that suggestion recommends and see what happens. The error message is pretty clear.

Answer (score 5):

I wrapped the child in a `<div>` and it works.